# Using IFERROR in VBA Formulae

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I'm trying to use VBA to copy information from various different files in a folder, however, in some files the heading is "Net Retail Price" and in some "NRP".

My code looks for the heading text to find the column, and then copies the information from that column. I need a way to search for "Net Retail Price", and then if it can't find that search for "NRP".

So far I can look for "Net Retail Price", and if it doesn't find it, it searches for "NRP". But if it is the other way round (i.e. the heading is Net Retail Price) it throws an error.

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Mastersht As Worksheet
Dim PasteRow As Long
Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnCol As Long

'Copy out NRP
lnRow = 3
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
lnCol = sh.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Net Retail Price", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
ErrorHandler:
    lnCol = sh.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="NRP", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    sh.Range(Cells(lnRow + 2, lnCol), Cells(i, lnCol)).Copy
    Mastersht.Range("F" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: On my phone at the moment so don't want to answer with untested code. You could perform a `REPLACE` and change all instances of NRP to Net Retail Price and then perform a single `FIND`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest getting rid of the error handler and instead code for each scenario:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Mastersht As Worksheet
Dim PasteRow As Long
Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnCol As Long

'New variables
Dim i As Long
Dim rngFound As Range


'Copy out NRP
lnRow = 3

Set rngFound = sh.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Net Retail Price", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
If rngFound Is Nothing Then
    Set rngFound = sh.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="NRP", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If rngFound Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find neither NRP nor Net Retail Price." & Chr(10) & "Aborting..."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        lnCol = rngFound.Column
    End If
Else
    lnCol = rngFound.Column
End If

sh.Range(sh.Cells(lnRow + 2, lnCol), sh.Cells(i, lnCol)).Copy
Mastersht.Range("F" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Changes:

- Try to find "Net Retail Price" first
- if found set `lnCol` accordingly
- if not found try finding "NRP"
- if found set `lnCol` accordingly
- if not found then pass out a message box that neither was found and
  abort

Comment: I do not see where `i` is assigned a value.  Am I missing it?

Comment: @ScottCraner There are lots of things missing. The OP failed to give us the complete code. As such `Set Masterwb = ...` is missing as well as `Set wb = Thisworkbook`. I am not sure where `i` is initiated in his / her code. Must be missing too. But since I saw the variable being used in the original post I thought it should be (at least) declared with a `Dim`. So, not really entirely new. Just now also declared....

Comment: Sorry the original code contains loads more stuff so tried to cut it down and missed a few things. Thanks very much for your answer! Really helped

Answer (score 0):

I would set both variables within OnError handlers:

```
Col1: NPR;
Col2: Net Retail Price.
```

Then, I would prompt the macro to copy both columns, within OnError handlers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest inserting

```
On Error Goto 0
Exit Sub
```

To your code

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim Masterwb  As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim Mastersht As Worksheet
Dim PasteRow As Long
Dim lnRow As Long
Dim lnCol As Long

'Copy out NRP
lnRow = 3
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
lnCol = sh.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="Net Retail Price", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error Goto 0
sh.Range(Cells(lnRow + 2, lnCol), Cells(i, lnCol)).Copy
Mastersht.Range("F" & PasteRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    lnCol = sh.Cells(lnRow, 1).EntireRow.Find(What:="NRP", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

You have also not defined variable i in

```
sh.Range(Cells(lnRow + 2, lnCol), Cells(i, lnCol)).Copy
```

Note that there is possible to have another error handler to handle errors in the first error handler.